# VSTS Build Fail on NuGet Installer

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

Trying to migrate from XAML deployment to VSTS CI & CD.  Can't get past this build failure:

---

Starting: NuGet restore **\DFWSPFWebsite*.sln

## ******************************************************************************

Task         : NuGet Installer
Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
Version      : 0.2.29
Author       : Microsoft Corporation

## Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)

C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Error: No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\s***.sln
Packages failed to install

---

Finishing: NuGet restore **\DFWSPFWebsite*.sln

---

Answer (score 0):

First please check if you have the solutions match `DFWSPFWebsite*.sln` in your project.

If you want to select packages.config, just select packages.config for **Path to solution or packages.config** as below pictures. So you should use `DFWSPFWebsite/DFWSPFWebsite/packages.config` instead of `**\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\packages.config` in your configuration.

[image]

[image: second]

Comment: There is only the single DFWSPFWebsite.sln contained in the "DFWSPFWebsite" folder which has the regretably confusing "DFWSPFWebsite" Project folder.  Although I have used Package Manager to install NuGet.VisualStudio, NuGet.Common, NuGet.Core and now finally, NuGet.Configuration - I still do not have a NuGet.config file anywhere locally in the sln folder tree.

Comment: This same solution builds & runs just fine locally and never failed to deploy to Azure via XAML.

Comment: If you have only one `.sln` file, just click `...` button and choose the file for **Path to solution or packages.config**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make VSTS Build find my NuGet packages with guidance from @Marina and these additional settings:

Path to solution or packages.config = **\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\packages.config

Disable local cache = true

NuGet arguments = -PackagesDirectory $(build.sourcesDirectory)\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\

Also, make sure the NuGet Version is correct.

Comment: You can select the file path, so it should not contain wildcard characters. I updated my answer, you can config by the way I shared in the pictures.